# MySql splitting column values

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv

I have column with separated data.

```
1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908
```

Does exist any MYSQL function which will split column into 0..N strings separated by comma?

And then check if this split vale from column is inside array statement - column value IN (7990).

Comment: You could try [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). It's intended for strings so I am not 100% sure how well it will work for numbers; I don't have much experience with, as fields containing multiple/comma-separated values are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does exist any MYSQL function which will split column into 0..N
>   strings separated by comma?

A upgrade on GMB answer would be, which is using a number generator to automatically split the strings, with nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` functions.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
     t.val 
   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.val, ',', number_generator.row_number),   ',', -1) parsed_val
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS row_number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2  
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN 
 t
```

**Result**

```
| val                           | parsed_val |
| ----------------------------- | ---------- |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 1223       |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 7990       |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 8373       |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 3892       |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 7654       |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 8908       |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8wm52U4ZDAWpSjCpHHfeS3/4)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @bukaj.multis be a good sportsman and also upvote GMB as this answer is a upgrade based on his answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I like your answer too (and your sportmanship)!

Answer (score 1):

To split the CSV string into parts, here is a solution that uses [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT
    val,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',1), ',', -1) val1, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',2), ',', -1) val2, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',2), ',', -1) val3
FROM t;
```

This will give you the first three matches. You can add freely more columns to the query to capture more CSV parts.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8wm52U4ZDAWpSjCpHHfeS3/0)**:

```
| val                           | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| ----------------------------- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1223,7990,8373,3892,7654,8908 | 1223 | 7990 | 7990 |
```

---

On the other hand, if you just want to check if a given value is part of the CSV string, you can simply use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), like:

```
SELECT val FROM t WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1223', val);
```

Comment: *"This will give you the first three matches. You can add freely more columns to the query to capture more CSV parts."* + 1 i've posted a answer which can do it automatically